# How to access youtube video statistics history using google's youtube data api?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm just starting to look into the google youtube data api. I am wondering if there is an option to look at statistical history instead of just getting the up to date statistics?

I see when on a youtube video you can access this information by clicking 'more > statistics', but I'm not able to see an option on the [youtube data api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to do the same.

code snippets of what I'm using to pull up to date info at the moment;

```
    self.APIs = {
        'videos': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
        'search': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
    }

   def get_video_info(self, video_id):
        api_url = manager.get_api('videos')
        params = {
            'id': video_id,
            'part': 'id, snippet, contentDetails, player, statistics, status'
        }

        video = manager.api_request(api_url, params)
        return video



    exampleGen = method.video_search('hello', 5).items
```

If it is not possible using the data api, will it be possible to do something similar through the use of a web crawler?

Apologies if the obvious answer is no here, I've been googling for the past few hours and can't find any solutions. I can see that socialblade.com seems to display historical data, but again I'm not sure if they do it by caching data themselves, using a web crawler or by using the youtube data api. Any advice is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/) can do that.

Comment: @paolo I did spend some time looking at this but it seems that YouTube Analytics only allows you to view your own youtube channels/videos data and not other peoples views/likes etc?

Comment: Just confirming that you can only use YouTube Analytics API for the channels and videos you own. If want data from the videos/channels you don't own, you can ask them if they'd share it to you. Otherwise, you have to use a 3rd party service (like what you already included in your post -- socialblade). PS: Don't really have any experience using socialblade or any similar service, so I can't provide any additional comments on that area. Cheers!